# How can I get Views pages with taxonomy arguments display to fire after URL Alias (Path Auto)?

Tags: 7, path-aliases, views

Right now I have a Views page that shows all results of the content type it filters by. If there is a taxonomy argument present (Contextual argument: Taxonomy ID: validate by Name to taxonomy ID) then of course it filter those results as specified.

Everything works fine. My views structure is this:

Page:  for-sale (displays all for sale items).

w/ argument: for-sale/cars (filter just the items that have the taxonomy ID cars).

Everything falls apart when I turn on Path Auto. Path auto has to have the name as my views path with argument.

Before I turn path auto on, my views with argument display correctly. Once I switch it on, taxonomy takes over, and I get the default list of taxonomy terms as if you were viewing them at taxonomy/term/ID.

Obviously path auto, or url aliases, to show taxonomy is firing after my views and rerendering their output.

How can I reverse this? How can I have views fire after PathAuto and maintain the integrity of my view with argument?  I know there are a couple modules out there that could help, but I would rather adjust the firing order (weights) in Drupal somehow so that I can void the overhead of a module for just this.

Note, if you are wondering why I am trying to get these to work at the same aliased URL, it's all about duplicate content.  For-sale/cars shows the same thing (more or less) as taxonomy/term/23. I need global redirect to automatically handle this issue.  Please leave a comment if you know if a way to achieve this differently than how I am currently trying to achieve it.

Comment: Did you have the default taxonomy/term/termID views enabled?

Comment: I have turned that on and off, but saw no difference. perhaps I am not using it correctly. If I have that on,  should I remove contextual filters from my other views for taxonomny ID?

Comment: If you have that on, regardless of other views configured for taxonomy, the default taxonomy/term/ID view will be used. Perhaps you can try this module: TVI (Taxonomy Views Integrator). What it does is it will override the default taxonomy/term/termID views and use TVI for taxonomy to respect your own views. Hence, for-sale/cars path can now be used to access your content.

Comment: I dont' think there is a 'weight-firing' option as you have mentioned. I have used the TVI module above for my own site.